# Can I add the process name to cgroup tasks but not PID?

Tags: linux, docker, cgroups

I need to use the *./cgroup/cpu* tool to limit the CPU usage of a particular process. At present, I have achieved this, but every time I have to start the process first, then get the PID of the process, and then write the PID to the tasks file.

Considering this scenario, I need to use gzip tool periodically to compress some data. Every time gzip is started, its process PID is incremented, and compression usually ends quickly. In this case, it is very tedious to write gzip process PID to *./cgroup/cpu/mytestnode/tasks* every time.Is there a better way? For example, write the process name into tasks but not PID.

Comment: This should help https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/starting_a_process

Answer (score 1):

You can use docker to manage the resources for you in a more higher level. Docker allows you to limit the container to a cpu set. Take this example of limiting all of the processes in the container to the CPUs 2,3 and 5, and verifying that the `cgroup` is indeed limited:

```
~$ docker run -ti --rm --cpuset-cpus=2,3,5 ubuntu:20.04 more /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/cpuset.cpus
2-3,5
```

So to run `gzip` and compress `somefile` on the in your current folder, running only on CPU 1, you can start docker as follows:

```
~$ docker run -ti --rm --cpuset-cpus=1 -v $(pwd):/work ubuntu:20.04 gzip /work/somefile
```

In addition to CPU stickiness, Docker will allow you to mange the CPU quota. Following is the same example, but limiting to only 1% of the CPU=1

```
docker run -ti --rm --cpuset-cpus=1 --cpus=0.01 -v $(pwd):/work ubuntu:20.04 gzip /work/somefile
```

You can see other options of controlling the resources in the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your gzip processes are all started by some script. If so, you can make the script enter *its own PID*, or precisely, the PID of shell running the script, into the cgroup, then start all the archive processes as required, and they will all end up in the same cgroup by being child processes.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $$ > /cgroup/cpu/mytestnode/tasks
# here go all your gzip calls
```

If not, but the task is called from somewhere, you can wrap the gzip command into such a script, or call echo then gzip as an inline script for `bash -c` command.